# Подтверждение личности для «Instagram Basic Display»

Tags: api, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

хочу сделать виджет, который выводит последние записи с Instagram через API Instagram Basic Display.

Результаты проверки приложения (с тестовым юзером) - одобрено. Но для того, чтоб оно работало с обычным аккаунтом - нужно ещё пройти "Подтверждение личности", но там пишет, что "В связи с пандемией коронавируса (COVID-19) мы временно приостановили выполнение процедуры подтверждения личности".

когда я пытаюсь получить долгосрочный маркер доступа, выходит ошибка:

```
"error":{
    "message":"Unsupported get request.",
    "type":"IGApiException",
    "code":100,
    "fbtrace_id":"Adp0w1IcE5a7AZPzvhBnrRk"
}
```

Полазив по форумам, я понял, что нужно верифицировать приложение и подписать контракт, а этого сделать никак нельзя, так как они приостановили проверку личности из-за короновируса.

У меня просто мозг взрывается, с одной стороны скоро в инстаграме перестанет работать старый api, а с другой на новом работает только тестовый юзер.

P.S. там ещё можно подтвердить компанию, но этого физически не могу сделать, так как у меня нет никакой компании.

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с подобным?